# Не запускается отладочный сервер Django

Tags: django, сервер

пытаюсь запустить отладочный сервер Джанго. Ввожу в командной строке manage.py runserver, но сервер не запускается, а вместо этого открывается файл manage.py в редакторе кода. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло, а почему на другом компьютере я не вводил слово 'python', но сервер запускался?

Comment: @Maksimilian ну у меня когда стоял вижуал студио тоже так было. не понимает через что запускать что-ли . поэтому надо указывать что питоном